# How to add an option from a drop down menu into a select box?

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery code below where an option which has been selected from a drop down menu is removed from the drop down menu:

```
            var selectedOption = jQuery("#modulesDrop option:selected");
            selectedOption.remove();
```

But before I perform the remove, I want to add the content from the drop down menu into a select box, but the problem is that I don't seem to know how to do this. I tried the code below but all that did was remove the option from the drop down menu as above and did not add the option into the select box:

```
        var selectedOption = jQuery("#modulesDrop option:selected");
        selectedOption.appendTo("#moduleExistForm");
        selectedOption.remove();
```

Comment: sorry if this is a weird question... but what do you mean by drop down menu and select box? aren't they the same thing?

Comment: @BrianGlaz I meant a multiple drop down menu which height and width has been modified so that it looks like a box. I didn't know what the exact term was so I called it a select box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `remove()` because `appendTo()` automatically detaches the element from its original parent then appends it on the new element that you specify:

```
<select id="old">
<option value="dog">dog</option>
<option value="cat">cat</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="add" id="add"/>

<select id="new">
</select>​
<script>
   $('#add').click(function(){
     var x = $('#old option:selected');
     x.appendTo($('#new'))
    });​
</script>
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8MAny/

Answer (score 1):

```
 var selectedOption = jQuery("#modulesDrop option:selected");
 var appendedObject = '<div>Something</div>';
 selectedOption.before(appendedObject);
 selectedOption.remove();
```

The .append() method inserts the specified content as the last child
So if you have selected object use before or after methods.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the .remove(). By using appendTo(), you're moving that element from its current location to the new location.

If you just want the content to move then save the value to a variable and append that instead.

```
var selectedOption = jQuery("#modulesDrop option:selected"),
    selectedOptionValue = selectedOption.val();
selectedOptionValue.appendTo("#moduleExistForm");
selectedOption.remove();
```